# Azure drive shares

Tags: azure, mapping, drive, shares

Azure drive shares, I attached storage to my main Azure server for my other servers to access via network locations as a mapped drive, since I have shutdown the servers over the weekend they are no longer able to connect, any ideas ?

Getting the error network path not found.

Comment: If you shut it down it more then likely came back with a different ip address, and depending on your dns configuration it may not have updated it

Comment: How can I set this up so that if servers are turned off that they can access a share ? I have 4 server 2012 instances with 1 server being used as the core box for operations, this has the primary connection for the shared drive, it is also has AD and DNS. I used this link to create the shared drive     http://www.gregpakes.co.uk/post/create-a-shared-drive-using-azure-files

Comment: If all your machines are in the same virtual network, make sure they are configured to use your azure DNS server as their DNS servers. Make sure you don't turn that machine off.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-manage-dns-in-vnet/

Comment: Thanks, that's where I've gone wrong is there anyway I can set this back up without getting rid of the drive "now that I know NOT to turn the core box off" ?

Comment: Once you through this process it should update, and work as is

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Azure File storage, which will allow other Azure servers to access files via SMB, without needing a server to host the share - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/